Bras, kets and operators for a free particle in spherical coordinates
Suppose I have a particle in 3D space. I can describe its quantum state as $|\psi\rangle \in \mathcal{H}$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is some Hilbert space. I may be interested in the position operator $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$. I may be interested in a transition "matrix" element
$$
\langle \psi'|\hat{\mathbf{r}}|\psi\rangle
$$
but
$$
\hat{\mathbf{r}} = \hat{x}\mathbf{e}_x + \hat{y}\mathbf{e}_y + \hat{z}\mathbf{e}_z
$$
I can (crudely) write
$$
|\psi\rangle = \int\int\int \psi(x, y, z)(|x\rangle\otimes |y\rangle\otimes|z\rangle)dxdyz
$$
where
$$
\begin{align*}
\hat{x}|x\rangle =& x|x\rangle\\
\hat{y}|y\rangle =& y|y\rangle\\
\hat{z}|z\rangle =& z|z\rangle\\
\end{align*}
$$
I think this corresponds to a decomposition of the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_x \otimes \mathcal{H}_y \otimes \mathcal{H}_z$. Note that e.g. $\mathcal{H}_x$ is an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, but it corresponds to the Hilbert space of a particle in one-dimension.
We can calculate
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle \psi'|\hat{\mathbf{r}}|\psi\rangle =& \int\int\int\int\int\int (\langle x'|\otimes \langle y'|\otimes \langle z'|) \psi^{'*}(x', y', z')(\hat{x}\textbf{e}_x + \hat{y}\textbf{e}_y +\hat{z}\textbf{e}_z)\psi(x, y, z)(|x\rangle \otimes |y\rangle \otimes |z\rangle) dxdydzdx'dy'dz'\\
=& \int\int\int\int\int\int\psi^{'*}(x',y',z')(x\mathbf{e}_x + y\mathbf{e}_y + z\mathbf{e}_z)\psi(x, y, z) \delta(x-x')\delta(y-y')\delta(z-z')dxdydzdx'dy'dz'\\
=& \int\int \int |\psi(x, y, z)|^2 (x\mathbf{e}_x + y \mathbf{e}_y + z \mathbf{e}_z)dxdydz
\end{align*}
$$
I've used $\langle x'|x\rangle = \delta(x-x')$ and likewise for $y$ and $z$ together with the integration rules for dirac delta "functions" $\delta$.

My question is what is the exactly analogous way to perform this calculation using spherical coordinates? I know we can expand
$$
\hat{\mathbf{r}} = \hat{a}_{-1}\mathbf{e}_{-1} + \hat{a}_0 \mathbf{e}_0 + \hat{a}_{+1}\mathbf{e}_{+1}
$$
where
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{e}_0 =& \mathbf{e}_z\\
\mathbf{e}_{\pm1} =& \mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\mathbf{e}_x \pm i \mathbf{e}_y)
\end{align*}
$$
with $\hat{a}_q$ (for $q\in \{-1, 0, +1\}$) calculated accordingly.
But my question is how to analogously write
$$
|\psi\rangle = \int\int \int \psi(x, y, z)(|x\rangle \otimes |y\rangle \otimes |z\rangle)dx dy dz
$$
and the action of $a_q$ on this state. I want to write it something like
$$
|\psi \rangle = \int \int \int \psi(r, \theta, \phi) (|r\rangle \otimes |\theta, \phi\rangle) r^2\sin(\theta) dr d\theta d\phi
$$
but I have remaining questions like how do $a_q$ act on $|r\rangle \otimes |\theta, \phi\rangle$ and how exactly is $(\langle r'|\otimes \langle \theta', \phi'|)(|r\rangle \otimes |\theta, \phi\rangle)$ evaluated?
Some notes:

I realize I'm playing fast and loose with physics notation here and that states like $|x\rangle$ are not well-defined in a naive sense. However, this is a typical abuse of notation and I understand that it can be made rigorous if one desires. If possible, I would like an answer at an equal level of mathematical abuse as this one. A higher level of mathematical rigor might be ok, or it might just be throwing more math at me than I can/want to handle right now.
I've written $|r\rangle \otimes |\theta, \phi\rangle$ instead of $|r\rangle \otimes |\theta\rangle \otimes |\phi\rangle$. Is the former actually more appropriate? If so, why? I think the answer is related to the fact that we partition $\mathcal{H}$ as $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_r \otimes \mathcal{H}_{\theta, \phi}$ where $\mathcal{H}_{\theta, \phi}$ is something like a Hilbert space for a particle on a unit sphere or an abstract sphere.
Of course $\psi(r, \theta, \phi)$ will likely be decomposed as something like $\psi(r, \theta, \phi) = R_{nl}(r)Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi)$. That is fine and helpful, but it is besides the point of this question. I'm specifically interested in how the bras, kets, operators, differentials and dirac deltas (not the wavefunctions) should be handled in the spherical coordinates case.


Some guesses towards the right direction. I think the answer has something to do with
$$
\begin{align*}
a_{\pm 1} =& \mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x \pm i y) = \mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} r \sin(\theta) e^{\pm i\phi}\\
a_0 =& z = r\cos(\theta)
\end{align*}
$$
This expression is true for c-number coordinate variables $a_q$, $x, y, z$ and $r, \theta, \phi$ but note the lack of hats.
We can generalize this to operators I guess to allow us to do something like
$$
\hat{a}_{\pm 1} (|r\rangle \otimes |\theta, \phi\rangle) \sim \mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \hat{r} \widehat{\sin(\theta)} \widehat{e^{\pm i\phi}} (|r\rangle \otimes |\theta, \phi \rangle) \sim \mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} r \sin(\theta) e^{\pm i \phi} (|r\rangle \otimes |\theta, \phi \rangle)
$$
Note the weird use of widehats... The issue is I don't know how to (crudely or otherwise) justify these steps in terms of operators and bras/kets.
One way to frame the question is: How is $|r\rangle \otimes |\theta, \phi\rangle$ defined (in terms of $|x\rangle \otimes |y\rangle \otimes |z\rangle$?) to ensure that $\hat{a}_{\pm 1} \sim \hat{x} \pm i\hat{y}$ acts on it with eigenvalue $\sim r\sin(\theta)e^{\pm i \phi}$?

Another step, perhaps approaching an answer. Perhaps we have
$$
|r\rangle \otimes |\theta, \phi\rangle = |x: r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\rangle \otimes |y: r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\rangle \otimes |z: r\cos(\theta)\rangle
$$
Then I think acting $\hat{a}_{\pm 1, 0}$ on $|r\rangle \otimes |\theta, \phi\rangle$ would give the desired effect.
We would also have
$$
\begin{align*}
&\int\int\int (\langle r'|\otimes \langle \theta', \phi'|) f'(r', \theta', \phi')f(r, \theta, \phi) (|r\rangle \otimes |\theta, \phi\rangle) r'^2\sin(\theta')dr'd\theta'\phi'\\
=& \int\int\int \delta(r\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) - r'\sin(\theta')\cos(\phi'))\delta(r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) - r'\sin(\theta')\sin(\phi'))\delta(r\cos(\theta) - r'\cos(\theta'))f'(r', \theta', \phi')f(r, \theta, \phi)r'^2\sin(\theta')dr'd\theta'\phi'
\end{align*}
$$
which, if you do the change of coordinates properly, may neatly work out simply to
$$
f'(r, \theta, \phi)f(r, \theta, \phi)
$$

Your question is extremely long... anyway, yes, you have an isomorphism $L^2(\mathbb R^3)\to L^2(\Omega, \mu)$ where $\mu$ is the measure in spherical coordinates. And moreover, $L^2(\Omega,\mu)=L^2(\Omega_r, \mu_r) \otimes L^2(\Omega_s, \mu_s)$, where the former is the radial part and the latter the angular part. Does that help?

@TobiasFünke I think it's likely I'm exactly asking for a proof or construction employing bra/ket notation of the isomorphism you are talking about. I've never seen the notation $L^2(\Omega, \mu)$. What can I look up to learn more about what you mean by that? Also to learn more about the decomposition $L^2(\Omega_r, \mu_r) \otimes L^2(\Omega_s, \mu_s)$

The bra-ket notation is just notation, it should not affect any proof or conceptual understanding...what I've written is standard textbook knowledge...but I think Valter Moretti has also some answers here, regarding this (and you can check his book). I know by heart that chapter 7.2. in Prugovečki's QM book deals with this. Unfortunately, I don't have time to spell out an answer.

Yes, Moretti's textbook example 157 seems to cover this. Unfortunately that example is basically at the end of the book and requires a lot of prior knowledge from the rest of the textbook (which I don't yet have). I'm not familiar with Prugovečki's book but I can check it.

Sophistication or not, make sure you have the standard background text by Sakurai and Napolitano, Modern Quantum Mechanics, e.g., 3rd edition, under your belt, and especially Sec (3.6.2) and eqn (3.319).
